# python dictionary of classes, values disappearance

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I'm trying to assign a dictionary of classes as value, and strings as keys.
I have correct values when printing them inside the main loop,
but as soon as i leave the main loop, my "cliStat" variable appears just initialized
with "O" values..

Here's the portion of the code where i do the assignment and the printing.
My question is, why does cliStat remains with "0" values ?

```
cliStat = {}
for org in client:

        cliStat[ org ] = StatEntry( org, "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0" ) 


self.getFilteredStat( client, date_debut, date_fin )

for statEntry in self.tabStatEntry.values():

        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].nb_users += statEntry.nb_users
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].nb_pages = ( statEntry.nb_pages + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].nb_pages ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_rate = ( statEntry.perf_rate + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_rate ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].response_time = ( statEntry.response_time + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].response_time ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].nb_errors = ( statEntry.nb_errors + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].nb_errors ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_globale = ( statEntry.perf_globale + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_globale ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_server = ( statEntry.perf_server + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_server ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_network = ( statEntry.perf_network + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_network ) / 2
        cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_redirect = ( statEntry.perf_redirect + cliStat[ statEntry.client ].perf_redirect ) / 2


for cle,val in cliStat.items():

        print val
```

Here's the full code if needed ; http://dpaste.com/914508/

If you need to run the code, here are the data files http://rapidshare.com/files/2185155450/meteo.7z

Just change the logDir variable with your folder.

Thanks for Having a look !

Comment: Note: you do not need to surround types with `()`, like `(int)`, to do casting. Just do `int(object)`.

Comment: Are you sure you are adding non-zero values? `(0 + 0) / 2 == 0`

Comment: yes sure, i thought about that, but even nb_users stays at 0, and
printing them in the main loop gives non zero value

Comment: Could you make a simplified runnable example? The code in dpaste depends on some data files.

Comment: @Janne Karila :
Here's some data file : http://rapidshare.com/files/2185155450/meteo.7z

Just change the logDir variable with the new folder.
You'll have runnable code.. thanks for looking into it !

Comment: sorry Janne Karila : i just changed the rights, should be good now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all objects remain filled with zeros.

I changed the last loop to

```
    for cle,val in cliStat.items():
        if val.nb_users:
            print val
```

and got an output of six clients, all filled with non-zero data.

It would be good to test the code first with a small amount of data.